# How to register a JSDoc definitions globally for project for intellisense?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-2017, jsdoc

I made a documentation for our JSON data that are oftentimes passed as parameters:

```
/**
  * @typedef {Object} LIBRARY_JSON 
  * @property {object} googleAnalytics Google analytics settings
  * @property {Array<String>} genres list of genres for filtering, if applicable
  * @property {Array<LIBRARY_ITEM>} narrations list of audio files
  */
```

It works, with intellisense if I write function like this:

```
/**
 * @param {LIBRARY_JSON} lib
**/
function test(lib) {

}
```

When I hover `lib`, I get the info I need. But of course, only in the file where I'd written it. How to register it for whole project?

I don't want to `import` a file that contains just comments, so I'd really like to do it in project settings.